# Unable to select latest python version in PyCharm Fedora 39

Tags: fedora, python3, pycharm

I recently switched to using Fedora 39. I installed PyCharm Community Edition and started with and found that I can not switch to the latest python version.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.12.1
```

In the PyCharm python interpreter section the path is `/usr/bin/python3` and version is 3.10.

```
$ pwd
/usr/bin
$ ls -lrt | grep python
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       16032 Jul 19  2023 abrt-action-analyze-python
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root          65 Jul 20  2023 mcomix3 -> ../..//usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mcomix3/mcomix3starter.sh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root          68 Jul 20  2023 comicthumb -> ../..//usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mcomix3/comicthumbstarter.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root        1921 Sep 14 05:30 register-python-argcomplete
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root         387 Sep 14 05:30 python-argcomplete-tcsh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root        2559 Sep 14 05:30 python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root        3476 Sep 14 05:30 activate-global-python-argcomplete
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root          16 Dec 18 05:30 python-config -> ./python3-config
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root          17 Dec 18 05:30 python3-config -> python3.12-config
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root        3079 Dec 18 05:30 python3.12-x86_64-config
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       15888 Dec 18 05:30 python3.12
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root          10 Dec 18 05:30 python3 -> python3.12
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root           9 Dec 18 05:30 python -> ./python3
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root        3026 Feb 16 13:42 python3.12-config
```

How can I configure the python to the latest version.